# how to retain viewstate for the dynamic controls created in GRIDVIEW

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i am creating dynamic textbox onRowCreated event in gridview control, however when i try to findcontrol i get null

here is how i am dong...

```
protected void gvORg_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if ((e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate)) || (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit))
    {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
              txBox txtReg = new TextBox();
              txtReg.ID = "_registration" + e.Row.RowIndex + rowId.ToString();
              txtReg.Text = reg.RegistrationToken;
              e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtReg);
         }
    }
}


  protected void gvOrg_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            .....
            ....
             TextBox _registration1 = gvOrg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("_registration" + e.RowIndex + rowId) as TextBox;   
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Templates? Then you may give the TextBox an ID and use FindControl method to get it.

Comment: the reason is that, i am creating textbox based on the count coming from database so i am not sure how many textboxs, it might be 1 or 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i able to fix my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807310/finding-control-in-collection-tree)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to find it by:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
(TextBox)gvr.FindControl("_registration" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + reg.RegistrationId.ToString())
```

Comment: i get this error:
`
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: i am still getting `null`; while debuggin i see that `gvr.DataItem` is `null` also