# finding control in collection tree

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i am adding dynamic control (textbox) and i set the property to `visible = false` but i dont find the control in the tree collection,   i want to hide it from user seeing it and read the value.

```
protected void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       Students org = (namespace.Students )(e.Row.DataItem);

       foreach (Registration reg in org.Registrations)
       {
          int _count = org.Registrations.Count;
          for (int rowId = 0; rowId < _count; rowId++)
          {
             TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
             txtBox.ID = "_registration" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rowId;
             txtBox.Text = reg.Name;
             txtBox.Visible = true;
             e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtBox);
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't add Row.RowIndex to your Textbox' ID. The NamingContainer for every control in a GridViewRow is the GridViewRow itself. Therefore you can and should use the same ID on the next row.

Comment: i am already using e.row.rowindex

Comment: @Time, i posted here why i end up using, may be you can shed some light? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798644/how-to-retain-viewstate-for-the-dynamic-controls-created-in-gridview

Comment: If you are using HtmlInputHidden then you dont have to set visible = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating the TextBoxesbased on org.Registrations, you can use a Repeater in the ItemTemplate of GirdVIew and then bind the org.Registrations as DataSource to the repeater in the RowCreated event.
i.e:
**in your aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ...... OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">
.
.
.
    <asp:TemplateField ...>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater id="rptRegistrations" runat="server">
                <asp:TextBox id="txtRegistration" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox><br/>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField ...>
</asp:GridView>
```

**in your code behind**

```
      protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)     
        {        
         if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
             Students org = (namespace.Students )(e.Row.DataItem);         
             Repeater rptrRegistrations = e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("rptrRegistrations") as Repeater ;
             rptrRegistrations.DataSource = org.Registrations;
             rptrRegistrations.DataBind();
         } 
        }

 public void gv_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = gvOrg.SelectedRow;
        Repeater rptrRegistrations = row.Cells[7].FindControl("rptrRegistrations") as Repeater;
        foreach(RepeaterItem item in rptrRegistrations.Items)
        {
            TextBox txtRegistration = item.FindControl("txtRegistration") as TextBox;
            //Now you have access to the textbox.
        }
  }
```

**Ignore the following text based on OP's comment**

Instead of creating the TextBox dynamically, add the Textbox in the Grid ItemTemplate in ASPX and then use e.Row.Cells.FindControl to access the textbox. Something like:

```
protected void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)     
{        
    Students org = (namespace.Students )(e.Row.DataItem);         
    foreach (Registration reg in org.Registrations)        
    {           
        int _count = org.Registrations.Count;           
        for (int rowId = 0; rowId < _count; rowId++)           
        {              
            TextBox txtBox = e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("txtRegistration") as TextBox ;
            //txtBox.ID = "_registration" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rowId;              
            txtBox.Text = reg.Name;              
            txtBox.Visible = true;              
            //e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(txtBox);          
        }        
    }     
}
```

Comment: i wish i could have used but i have a situation where i have to create dynamic control and i have already posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798644/how-to-retain-viewstate-for-the-dynamic-controls-created-in-gridview

Comment: Updated the post.. You might need to tweak the code posted a little to suit your needs..But it gives you the idea..

Comment: @Cybernate: if you look at my code and i am doing `for` loop statement to create # of textbox based on how many counts i get from db but looking at your code you have declarative text-box in .aspx page.... i am wondering how would that help in my situation?

Comment: i need something more dynamic

Comment: You are binding the Registrations to the repeater which in turn renders the textboxes based on items in Registrations. Try the code and you will figure out once you see it working...

Comment: It is still dynamic the textbox is wrapped in a repeater control which repeats the inner template as many times as items in the datasource bound to it.

Comment: getting null `Repeater rptrRegistrations = e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("rptRegistrations") as Repeater;` and double check that cells[7] is where i have my template for repeater

Comment: You need to check if the current row is DataRow in the RowCreated eventhandler and also make the handler to handle OnRowDataBound. Check the updated post.

Comment: i tried with both `OnRowCreated` & `OnRowDataBound` and still get the `null` when i was debuggin i did something like this

`e.Row.Cells[7].Text` i get this following
`
"\r\n<asp:Repeater id=\"rptRegistrations\"   > \r\n      <asp:TextBox id=\"txtRegistration\"   />             \r\n      </asp:Repeater>\r\n "`

Comment: Can you post the aspx part for the GridView you are using?

Comment: runat="Server" is missing for the Repeater control and the inner TextBox control. Also assing the Text attribute to the TextBox control to populate the Name property i.e. <asp:TextBox id="txtRegistration" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>

Comment: here is what i am getting the error:  after adding `runat="server" `Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' does not have a public property named 'TextBox'.`

Comment: @Abu: The answer which I gave is to give you idea to repeat the textbox dynamically. In the aspx file you are missing the ItemTemplate tag inside the Repeater and before the <asp:TextBox .. Please make sure that you have edited the aspx properly and then try to accomodate the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Cybernate, one last thing, how would i read those textbox created dynamically?

Comment: Have updated the post with a sample method by name: gv_SelectedIndexChanged Check the code (again it is to give you some idea, make syntactic corrections as needed)

Comment: while i was testing i found that if i set `<asp:TemplateField visible=false ....` then i am not getting any text value  ` TextBox txtRegistrationId = item.FindControl("txtRegistrationId") as TextBox;` its empty and if i set the `visible=true` on templatefiled then i am getting the value, any suggustions?

Comment: Why are you setting the Visible property to false? Shouldn't it be Visible to the end user? If yes, then use a asp:HiddenField instead of asp:TextBox

Comment: the reason i am using is to get the regId, i will try hiddenfield.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that putting Visible="false" onto a control with stop it rendering to the browser, so no, you won't find it.

Instead, you can try using an HtmlInputHidden control, which will generate a hidden input field.

Hidden fields aren't a great way of doing things since they're able to be modified fairly easily on the client side using various intercept tools.

Answer (score 0):

If visible is false, it wont be rendered to the page. Also for you requirement HTMLInputHidden control can be used.