# breaking foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, gridview

need help in tweaking my logic little bit.

as you see i have two `foreach loop` and both for different columns in gridview
this code is in OnRowUpdating in the gridview for more info what exactly i am doing you can see the closed thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807310/finding-control-in-collection-tree)

the problem is:

on every loop i will be updating a row to db but since i have two different loop it will not exit till the first loop finishes.

for an example: i have _rpt.Count = 2 so it will loop twice before it hit the second loop.

```
GridViewRow row = gv.SelectedRow;           
Repeater _rpt = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("rptReg") as Repeater;
Repeater _rpt1 = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].FindControl("rptVisitor") as Repeater;

foreach (RepeaterItem item in _rpt.Items)
{
    TextBox _txt = item.FindControl("txtId") as TextBox;
    TextBox _txt1 = item.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
    //update db
}

foreach (RepeaterItem item1 in _rpt1.Items)
{ 
    TextBox _txt3 = item1.FindControl("txtVisitor") as TextBox;
    //update db
}
```

is there a way that i can read both foreach loop values?

Comment: You're update is erroring due to `_txt3` assignment being inside the `if` block. You will need to put any references to within the scope of the `if` block, or otherwise ensure it is assigned to before being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a loop through multiple collections, and want to access each collection more than once, than a `foreach` may not be the best fit.

Try a regular `for` loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _rpt.Items.Count; i++)  
{  
    TextBox _txt = _rpt.Items[i].FindControl("txtId") as TextBox;  
    TextBox _txt1 = _rpt.Items[i].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;

    if (_rpt1.Items.Count > i)
        TextBox _txt3 = _rpt1.Items[i].FindControl("txtVisitor") as TextBox;

    //update db
}
```

The above will only work as expected `if (_rpt.Items.Count >= _rpt1.Items.Count)`, so be sure to check for and use the collection with the most items if they are ever going to be different.

Using a `foreach` loop enumerates the items within the single collection, allowing you a direct reference to each item within each iteration. This is handy if you are only accessing the one collection, as you don't need to use array indexers, and can just use the name you give it at the loop initialization.

It's not so handy when you are looping through multiple collections, as you ONLY have a reference to the collection used in the loop header.

Using a `for` loop allows you to keep track of which index you are at (using an `int`), allowing you to just use standard array notation to get the items in the collection.

Comment: @Jaymz: can you elaborate little bit more why foreach is not the best fit? - thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Abu - added extra explanation to answer. Not sure if it makes it any clearer though...

Comment: You're update is erroring due to `_txt3` assignment being inside the `if` block. You will need to put any references to within the scope of the `if` block, or otherwise ensure it is assigned to before being used.

Comment: i know that but its safe to initialize before it hits the `for loop` ? `TextBox __txt3 = new TextBox();`

Comment: Probably, but you should probably just use the _txt3 var inside the same conditional block, make sure it can only be used after it's been initialized to what you're going to use it as. So declare, initialize, and use, all within the same block.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in _rpt.Items)
{
    TextBox _txt = item.FindControl("txtId") as TextBox;
    TextBox _txt1 = item.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
    //update db

    TextBox _txt3 = _rpt1.Items[item.ItemIndex].FindControl("txtVisitor") as TextBox;

}
```

Comment: where is the `item1` coming from ?

Comment: Sorry, typo, please look again